# How can add wxWidgets as a dependency using bazel C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, bazel

I'm working on a C++ projects that depends on wxWidgets.

It's possible for me to compile the app using the following Makefile from the wxWidgets document:

```
PROGRAM = App
 
OBJECTS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))

# implementation

.SUFFIXES:      .o .cpp

.cpp.o :
    $(CXX) -O2 -g -c `wx-config --cxxflags` -o $@ $<

all:    $(PROGRAM)

$(PROGRAM):    $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -O2 -g -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJECTS) `wx-config --libs`

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(PROGRAM)
```

However, I decided to try bazel as my build system.

I'm getting the following error running `bazel build //src:app --verbose_failures:

```
In file included from external/wx/wx/defs.h:45,
                 from external/wx/wx/memory.h:14,
                 from external/wx/wx/object.h:19,
                 from external/wx/wx/utils.h:18,
                 from external/wx/wx/thrimpl.cpp:344:
external/wx/wx/platform.h:159:10: fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory
  159 | #include "wx/setup.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is my `WORKSPACE` file:

```
new_local_repository(
  name="wx",
  path="/usr/include/wx-3.2",

  build_file_content = """
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
    name = "headers",
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    includes = ["/usr/include/wx-3.2"],
)
"""
)

new_local_repository(
  name="gtk-unicode",
  path="/usr/lib/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.2",

  build_file_content = """
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
cc_library(
    name = "headers",
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"])
)
"""
)
```

`src/BUILD`:

```
cc_library(
  name="agent",
  srcs=["Agent.cpp"],
  hdrs=["Agent.h"],
  deps=[":game"]
)

cc_library(
  name="game",
  srcs=["Game.cpp"],
  hdrs=["Game.h"],
)

cc_binary(
  name="app",
  srcs=["App.cpp"],
  deps=[":agent", ":game", "@wx//:headers", "@gtk-unicode//:headers"],
  copts=[
    "-Iexternal/wx",
    "-Iexternal/gtk-unicode",
    "-DWXUSINGDLL",
    "-D__WXGTK3__",
    "-D__WXGTK__",
    "-pthread",
    "-lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.2",
    "-lwx_gtk3u_html-3.2",
    "-lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.2",
    "-lwx_gtk3u_core-3.2",
    "-lwx_baseu_xml-3.2",
    "-lwx_baseu_net-3.2",
    "-lwx_baseu-3.2"
  ]
)
```

Comment: Found this [similar](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=38455)  reference not sure if this can be helpful.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I've done your steps and run into the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty in answering this question is that, out of the box, wxwidgets provides a way to compile and link which goes against Bazel's philosophy. The steps differ a lot depending on the platform you are. Essentially, when you install wxwidgets, either compiling from source or from a premade OS package, it ships with the wx-config utility, which will generate through a shell command the flags you need for the compiler to work.

In Bazel, however, you need to declare the sources, headers, and definitions to Bazel itself, and then it will deduce the compiler flags. To make it work, you need to infer what the flags generated by wx-config mean in your platform, and then write them in Bazel. Here's how I did for the wxwidgets package in Ubuntu 22.04.

The output for wx-config --cxxflags is:

```
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0 -I/usr/include/wx-3.0 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXGTK__ -pthread
```

Notice that there are two include folders, three definitions, and the -pthread compiler option. For wx-config --libs we have:

```
-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread   -lwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_html-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0 -lwx_gtk3u_core-3.0 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0 -lwx_baseu-3.0
```

Here we have only one library folder, and a flag -lfoo in Linux translates to libfoo.so.

Anyway, when we translate this to Bazel, we need to add the following repos to the WORKSPACE file:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "wxheaders",
    build_file = "wxheaders.BUILD",
    path = "/usr/include/wx-3.0",
)

new_local_repository(
    name = "wxwidgets",
    build_file = "wxwidgets.BUILD",
    path = "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu",
)
```

For the wxheaders.BUILD file, put all headers you can find in the folder:

```
cc_library(
   name = "wxheaders",
   hdrs = glob(["**"]),
   includes = ["."],
   visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

For the wxwidgets.BUILD file, we have headers and shared libraries, and we can use

```
cc_library(
    name = "wxwidgets",
    srcs = [
        "libwx_gtk3u_xrc-3.0.so",
        "libwx_gtk3u_html-3.0.so",
        "libwx_gtk3u_qa-3.0.so",
        "libwx_gtk3u_adv-3.0.so",
        "libwx_gtk3u_core-3.0.so",
        "libwx_baseu_xml-3.0.so",
        "libwx_baseu_net-3.0.so",
        "libwx_baseu-3.0.so",
    ],
    hdrs = glob(["wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0/**"]),
    includes = [
        "wx/include/gtk3-unicode-3.0",
    ],
    defines = [
        "_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64",
        "WXUSINGDLL",
        "__WXGTK__",
    ],
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    deps = [
        "@wxheaders//:wxheaders",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Finally, when you are going to build a binary, add the missing -pthread in copts (we cannot add it in the dependency, since it doesn't propagate). The BUILD file should look like:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts = [
        "-pthread"
    ],
    deps = [
        "@wxwidgets//:wxwidgets",
    ],
)
```

Another alternative is to add the -pthread copt in the .bazelrc file, if you're OK with it being used in the entire project. There are several ways to go about it.

As mentioned before, the specific steps will depend a lot on your OS and how you installed wxwidgets, but I hope this example can get you started.

Comment: @FelipeLopez, thats why there is a good paradigm - if it works, it works. Don't change it and don't make it better. The best is an enemy of good

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is some elegant way of telling bazel to execute `wx-config` on its own, but in the worst case you can just copy-and-paste the output of `wx-config --cxxflags` into the `includes` assignment (and the same thing for `--libs`).

Comment: What is the `includes` assignment? Did you mean bazel command line arguments `--copt` and `--linkopt` respectively?

Comment: There is `includes = ["/usr/include/wx-3.2"],` above which is wrong/insufficient, so I thought about changing it. But doing it in `copts` would work too. The point is that you need to invoke the compiler with these flags.